# Accessing Gradle project properties outside of the build file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is it possible to reference project properties like sourceSets outside of the build file?  Is there an example I can follow?

Comment: Perhaps if you describe your use case something might come to mind.  You can get some information from commands like `./gradlew dependencies`.  Additionally, you could write custom tasks to OUTPUT virtually any information you want, in any format you want (text, csv, etc).  I think that might be your best bet, since you would need to run the build script in some measure for Gradle to do the actual work of assembling the values.

Comment: Hi @User51 

I had two vague ideas I might try to implement:

1. I want to be able to compiling java source code files on the fly and applying the classpaths from different predefined SourceSet depending on the package or dependencies that the source code files belonged to.  Keep in mind that the location and dependencies of these files are unknown at compile time, so I can't just predefine the sourceSet path.

2. I want to possible  pull maven dependencies at runtime depending on the requirements of the java code being compiled at runtime.